# Does SQL server 2019 allows to commit the data changes as similar to GIT

Tags: sql-server

I am doing an analysis to check in MSSQL 2019 to confirm whether it allows to take data backup of recent changes as similar to Git.

I need to go back to older data version if there is an need.
Any way to do this ?

Comment: SQL Server supports log backups that allow point-in-time restores (down to the individual transaction if you need to), system-versioned temporal tables and roll-your-own solutions with triggers, each with their own drawbacks and benefits. Look into backups first, as you need to take those anyway to ensure continuity. Note that all of these mechanisms require setup and maintenance -- unlike Git, which is designed for source control, SQL Server doesn't enable any of this by default, it just offers the features.

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine

1. backup/restore
2. log table and trigger

Answer (score 0):

Primarily you would use [backup and restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql) database or restore with *no-recovery* and apply [transaction log backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/apply-transaction-log-backups-sql-server) to get to a point-in-time restore.

There is also [system versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables) which has in-built support for logging changes to data in a table to capture historical changes.

Other options would be to roll your own bespoke solution using something like [change tracking or change-data-capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server), or even triggers for specific tables.